# "Unhandled Exception" but I DO handle it! It's a mystery (for me)

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter&Dart, when I try to send an udp packet and the screen of the emulator is turned off the sending fails. Ok.
The mystery is I cannot catch the failing in any way.
Udp socket send() is not async so try&catch is correct. If I add await nothing changes. If I try to append .catchError it is not permitted because it is not an async method.

```
             try {
               print(_udpSocket.toString());  //It prints Instance of '_RawDatagramSocket'

               _udpSocket!.send(_packet,_serverAddress!,Server_UdpPort);  //Send packet
             } catch (exception) {
               print("aaaaaaaaaaaa");  //It never prints aaaaa, it never executes this code

               print(exception.toString());
             }
```

Error in console:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Send failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1), address = 0.0.0.0, port = 0
E/flutter (25939): #0      _NativeSocket.send (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1213:34)
E/flutter (25939): #1      _RawDatagramSocket.send (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2460:15)
E/flutter (25939): #2      ClassServerConnection._handleOutcomingUdpStreamPacketsQueueEvent_async (package:meet2/2_1_4_ClassServerConnection.dart:1129:29)
E/flutter (25939): #3      ClassServerConnection._handleOutcomingUdpStreamPackets.<anonymous closure> (package:meet2/2_1_4_ClassServerConnection.dart:1090:93)
E/flutter (25939): #4      ClassQueue.callEvent.<anonymous closure> (package:meet2/2_1_2_ClassQueue.dart:78:68)
E/flutter (25939): #5      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:424:39)
E/flutter (25939): #6      Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (25939): #7      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (25939): #8      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (25939): #9      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

Comment: Is `send()` method async?

Comment: send() is not async

Comment: Does `send()` contains `async` code? Is it possible to see the implementation? Is it a custom implementation?

Comment: send() is just RawDatagramSocket send method: https://api.dart.dev/be/180360/dart-io/RawDatagramSocket/send.html

Comment: Because normally you cannot catch exceptions from async methods if you do not await them. This is due to the fact that code is execute in another context.

Comment: I know, but it's not an async method. As I wrote, I tried also with await and .catchError and it doesn't work.